# How Copy the Data from Azure CosmosDb to local using AzCopy tool?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, data-migration, azcopy

I want to copy the Data from the AzureCosmosDb Database\Container to the Local.

I am trying with the Azcopy tool. I have tried the query as per this [URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table/table-import#migrate-data-by-using-azcopy). But its not working.
The query which I have tried is as below :

```
Azcopy /Source:<Endpoint\Database\Container> /SourceKey:key /"<PrimaryKey>" /Dest:<Local Location> /EntityOperation:InsertOrReplace
```

What should I have to modify in this query to get the Data from Cosmos Db to my Local folder ?

Comment: is the account a Table API based?

Comment: Account is of SQL API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above method is recommended for Table API as mentioned in the doc, if you want to migrate data of SQL API use the [Data Migration Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/cosmosdb-migrationchoices).

Comment: Cool. This is working. But if I have to migrate the Data to the BlobStorage from AzureCosmosDb this tool will work ?